# Joint does not stop sliding

Tags: ros, gazebo, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have created a model of the sliding door in gazebo. This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="door_balcony">

  <gazebo reference="base_bac">
    <material>Gazebo/GrassFloor</material>
  </gazebo>
  <link name="world"/>
  <joint name="link_joint_bac" type="prismatic">
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
    <parent link="world"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 1.57" xyz="10.615 6.25 1.06"/>
    <limit effort="10.0" lower="-0" upper="0.8" velocity="0.5"/>
    <child link="link_bac"/>
    <dynamics damping="1" friction="10"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="link_bac">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="10"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.1" iyz="0.0" izz="0.1"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.8 0.06 2"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.8 0.06 2"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="link_bac">
    <material>Gazebo/RustySteel</material>
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

When I apply the joint effort it starts sliding from lower to higher limits.

```
rosservice call gazebo/apply_joint_effort '{joint_name: link_joint_bac, effort: 1, start_time: 10000000000, duration: 100000000}'
```

But when delete the joint force right at the time when the door is fully open, It does not stop sliding.

```
rosservice call gazebo/clear_joint_forces '{joint_name: link_joint_bac}'
```

Is there a mistake in my understanding or code ? Is there any other way to start and stop joint motion in gazebo ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39538/joint-does-not-stop-sliding/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1363 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can apply an opposite force instead of clearing the joint effort. I hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [gordon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2999/gordon/) with karma: 56 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2012-08-08**:
I solved the problem long back. Anyway, thanks!